# An unbeatable fortress of a singe vampire?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I thought if I seal a vampire in a 3x3 room with a chair, my fortress becomes unbeatable and I also get a free bookkeeper as a bonus.

When I went to this plan for the first time, the vampire worn off all her clothes, threw a tantrum and dead painfully in her cave.

Before going for it for the second time, what should get prepared for? Ok, I'll put a whole stockpile of clothes in the cave in advance. What else?

Comment: I have absolutely no useful input for your question, I just wanted to say that all your DF questions are making me want to finally try the game.

Comment: @miR You should definitely do it. It's incredibly fun, especially if you use the Masterwork mod.

Comment: I second @SaintWacko, no one regrets trying DF!

Comment: @DanielVartanov Oh, they might regret it when they realize it's 1 in the morning and they're still playing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As detailed [here](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/df2012:vampire#Uses), the key is to catch the vampire before he/she makes any friends. The death of friends is the primary cause of tantrums and insanity. Clothes rotting away also have an effect, so you might want to make a chute where new clothes can be dropped in for the vampire.

Besides just having an undead bookkeeper, you can also use your vampire as a lever-puller. Of course, this makes it even more important to keep them from going insane, unless you really want to have [!!FUN!!](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Losing). The first link has a few more ways to use vampires, as well.

Comment: Until vampires can climb walls like little short immortal spiders, anyways.

Comment: @Frank I'm sure there will be a way to set up the chute so it can't be climbed.  Two z-levels up in the center of the ceiling, perhaps?

Comment: Don't forget the emergency magma lever.